# How to remove the sidebar in Wordpress's posts?

Tags: wordpress, posts

In my posts I want to remove all the content that appears to the right, which contains things like search, recent stuff, archive, etc.

I want it to look more like a full-width page.

Any ideas?, preferably without having to manually touch any file, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got to admin panel.
You can find a menu `Appearance > Widgets` open that.
You now see a drag drop visual of you sidebar components. You can remove or modify there.